# Connecting two divs with a circle at the line's end

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating some cards that are to display a kind of timeline, and I want to do that by having some card divs with content that are connected with a line and with a circle at each of the ends of the line to make it look good. Currently I just have the cards, and I cannot figure out how to make the connected lines. I currently have something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="card-wrapper">
   <div class="card">
   </div>

   <div class="card">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-wrapper {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   align-content: center;
   flex-direction: row;
}

.card {
   width: 15rem;
   height: 25rem;
   background-color: #4090ff;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   margin: 2rem 4rem;
   box-shadow: 0.5rem 0.5rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L3h9xe5d/10/

And I want something like this:[image: Card Sketch]

Comment: how much do u want in same line? for example, two cards, three cards in a row

Comment: Do u want the connecting line text?

Comment: No, not the text. I just want the line that connects the cards, as well as the circles. How many cards in a row doesn't matter, I just need to be able to add and remove as needed.

Comment: ok will give ans.. pl wait.. 15 mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the above steps..

**HTML**

```
<div class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.card-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.card {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 25rem;
  background-color: #4090ff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2rem 4rem;
  box-shadow: 0.5rem 0.5rem 3rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
}
.card::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background-color: #4090ff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    content: "";
}
.card::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background-color: #4090ff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    content: "";
    z-index: 9;
}
.card:first-child::before,
.card:last-child::after,
.card:first-child .card-inner::before,
.card:last-child .card-inner::after {
    display: none;
}
.card-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.card-inner::after {
    position: absolute;
    right: -65px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: #000;
    content: "";
    width: 65px;
    height: 4px;
}
.card-inner::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -65px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: #000;
    content: "";
    width: 65px;
    height: 4px;
}
```